# A verb or noun for a 始発電車 arriving for passengers

Tags: phrase-requests, word-requests

Is there a name for a situation when a train departing from a source station (始発電車) arrives empty and waits for passengers?

For example, is there a way to ask if the train is already waiting on a platform, or when it will be ready for passengers? Like:

> 豊岡行はもう◯◯していますか
>   新宮行は発車の何分前◯◯しますか

I guess 到着 does not apply in this case, as the train does not formally arrive at the departing station. 準備していますか sounds too general on the other hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical term for that is  「[入線]{にゅうせん}」 for the noun and you can attach to it 「する/した/している, etc.」 to form a verb.

[入線 in 大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%85%A5%E7%B7%9A-593154#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)

Will you actually hear us "regular" native-speaker passengers use the term?  No, you rarely would if ever.  It would mostly be either a railroad employee or a rail buff who might use it.

The rest of the nation would use phrases such as:

> 「[始発]{しはつ}はもう[入]{はい}って（い）ますか。」
>
> 「始発はいつ入ってきますか/入りますか。」
>
> 「[東京]{とうきょう}行{い}きは[発車]{はっしゃ}の[何分前]{なんぷんまえ}に入ってきますか/入りますか。」

Answer (score 3):

As a Japanese, I say that you can use 「到着」

> 豊岡行はもう到着していますか
>
> 新宮行は発車の何分前に到着の予定ですか

BTW,  in an announce, they say「電車が参ります」 not 「電車が入ります」

EDIT: in a timetable 「着」 means 「到着」, 「発」 means 「出発」
https://gyazo.com/8eb94dcfe8fdcda546e5fadec01c22fe

Comment: OP is specifically asking about 始発列車.　「到着」 can be used for any train arriving at any station.

Comment: The "rest of the nation" uses 到着している or 来ている for 始発電車 anyway.

Comment: 私なら「XX行きはもう来てますか？」って言うかなと思います・・・(ホームに来てますか、みたいな意味で。)　または「XX行きは、もう乗れますか？」とか・・・？ (私は関西のことしか知らないので、他の方とちょっと違うのかもしれませんが。。。)

Comment: 「始発駅で」という質問です。始発駅に始発列車が「到着している」と言いますかね。私のイメージですが、一晩始発駅のどこかに停まっていた列車が朝一でホームに入るとき、「到着する」って言うでしょうか。

Comment: （「始発電車」は朝一番の電車という意味と、始点駅から出る電車という意味の両方があり、質問は後者の意味だと思いますが、それはともかく）　個人的には、深く考えず、どの状況でも「到着していますか」「来てますか」辺りを言います。駅のアナウンスとかの「1番線に到着の電車は…」と「1番線に入ります電車は…」にも始発駅かどうかで使い分けがあるんでしょうか（知らないだけ？）